# Do multiple threads in Java execute on different CPUs?

Tags: java, python, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety

In Python, threads are used in cases where the execution of a task involves some waiting. Simply put, Python threads are not executed on different CPUs.

For example, consider the CPU-bound function; count() in the programs below:

**performance_test_sequential.py**

```
import time 
def count(n):
    while(n > 0):
        n = n - 1;

def main():
    start_time = time.time();
    count(100000000);
    count(100000000);
    end_time = time.time();

    print("\n\n--- Total Execution Time: %s seconds ---" % (end_time - start_time));

if(__name__ == '__main__'):
main();`
```

**performance_test_threaded.py**

```
import threading
import time

class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, n):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self);
        self.n = n;

    def run(self):
        while(self.n > 0):
            self.n = self.n - 1;


def main():
    start_time = time.time();
    t1 = myThread(100000000);
    t2 = myThread(100000000);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    end_time = time.time();

    print("\nTotal Execution Time: %s seconds" % (end_time-start_time));

if(__name__ == '__main__'):
    main();
```

Execution times for these programs are:

**Sequential: 18.33 seconds**

**Threaded: 45.56 seconds(2.5X slower)**

This is due to [global interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), which prevents multiple native threads from executing Python bytecodes at once.
Simply putting, parallel programming this way is not possible in Python.

I made the same programs in Java, and execution time of threaded program was almost half in this case unlike Python:

**PerformanceTestSequential.java**

```
import java.util.*;
public class PerformanceTestSequential
    {
        int N;
        public PerformanceTestSequential(int n)
        {
            this.N = n;
        }

        public void run(){ 
            while(this.N > 0)
            {
                (this.N)--; 
             }
        }


// 
public static void main(String args[]){ 


PerformanceTestSequential thread1 = new PerformanceTestSequential(1000000000);
PerformanceTestSequential thread2 = new PerformanceTestSequential(1000000000);


long startTime = System.nanoTime();
thread1.run();
thread2.run();
long endTime   = System.nanoTime();
long totalTime = endTime - startTime;

System.out.println("\n\nExecution Time: " + (double)totalTime / 1000000000);

    }  
}`
```

**PerformanceTestThreaded.java**

```
import java.util.*;
public class PerformanceTestThreaded extends Thread
{
    int N;
    public PerformanceTestThreaded(int n)
    {
        this.N = n;
    }

    public void run(){ 
    while(this.N > 0)
    {
        //System.out.print(n);
        (this.N)--;

    }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){ 


    PerformanceTestThreaded thread1 = new PerformanceTestThreaded(1000000000);
    PerformanceTestThreaded thread2 = new PerformanceTestThreaded(1000000000);
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    try {
        //System.out.println("Waiting for thread 1 to finish.");
            thread1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Main thread Interrupted");
        }
    try {
        //System.out.println("Waiting for thread 2 to finish.");
        thread2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Main thread Interrupted");
        }
        long endTime   = System.nanoTime();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("\n\nExecution Time: " + (double)totalTime / 1000000000);

    }  
}
```

Execution Times:

**PerformanceTestSequential.java  = 1.816 seconds**

**PerformanceTestThreaded.java = 0.8697 seconds**

Unlike Python, here the threaded program is faster.

**My question is whether Threads in Java provide parallel programming, i.e. do the two different threads run on different available processors of the system, unlike Python?
I want to read more about how threads work in Java, please provide some resources.**

Please provide links to the documentation that explains how the different threads run on different processors in Java.

Comment: They might be.  They might not be.  Depends on what the operating system decides to do.

Comment: I read somewhere in the past that java does use multiple cores if it can, however I cannot find the source right now.
 [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330430/does-java-have-support-for-multicore-processors-parallel-processing) may help

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267269/green-threads-and-native-threads-in-java

Comment: _"I want to read more about how threads work in Java, please provide some resources."_ That question is off-topic for stack overflow, since it is a request for an off-site resource. I'd be surprised if it was specified though, seems like a VM implementation detail.

Comment: The fact that threads are used for "tasks that involve some waiting" has no bearing on whether or not they are scheduled on different CPUs.  You can port a multi-threaded Python program directly to Java without changing its logic at all, and the threads probably will run on different CPUs...

Comment: ..."probably" because the Java language specification does not say that different threads must run on different CPUs.  That decision is left up to the implementation.  The major Java implementations all use _native threads_, which means that they allow the operating system to decide which CPU runs which thread.  Python, by contrast, uses _green threads_, in which the all of the Python threads really run in a single operating system thread.  There may be some Java implementations out there that use green threads, but they are very far from the main stream.